# Angularfire: How to Filter with a Specific key or ID

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

So here is my quick code.

```
var thisisformykeyorid =$scope.id;

var ref = firebase.database().ref('/myusers/').child("users");
$scope.users= $firebaseArray(ref);
var query = ref.orderByChild("timestamp").limitToLast(100);
$scope.filteruser= $firebaseArray(query);
```

In my HTML is

```
 <div ng-repeat="samplein filteruser>
                <h2>{{ sample.firstname}}</h2>
                <p>{{ sample.age}}</p>  
 </div>
```

So in firebase there are unique id or keys for each set of data.
How do i add a filter or query to select a set of data from firebase using my variable ? (assuming $scope.id is a unique key) Please be guided that i dont want to use ng-repeat anymore because i only want to view **only 1 set of data**. Need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know what object you want to display, you can use `$firebaseObject` instead of `$firebaseArray`:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('/myusers/').child("users");
$scope.user = $firebaseObject(ref.child($scope.id));
```

And then display it in your HTML with:

```
<div >
    <h2>{{user.firstname}}</h2>
    <p>{{user.age}}</p>  
</div>
```